# Why is this ifstream failing to read flat object into memory?

Tags: c++, oop, serialization, io, ifstream

I have a flat object defined as follows:

```
class Student
{
public:
    char name[20];
    long num;

public:
    Student(char *name, long num) : num(num)
    {
        strcpy(this->name, name);
    }

    Student() : num(0)
    {
        strcpy(this->name, "");
    }

    void Serialize(ostream&);
    static Student Deserialize(istream&);
};
```

In the main function , I create an object as such :`Student stu("Hello", -1);` and then proceed to serialize it to a file which I then open again in an `ifstream`. Both the streams are opened in binary mode. When I try to retrieve the values in the deserialized object however, only the name is corerct while the number seems to be random memory gunk. Also, the `ifstream` exists with the fail bit set, indicating something went wrong. Here is the implementation of the deserialize function:

```
Student Student::Deserialize(istream &in)
{
    cout << "Starting deserialization (short)" << endl;
    Student stu;

    if (in.good())
    {
        in.read((char *) &stu, sizeof(Student));
    }
    if (in.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Deserialization failed (short)" << endl;
    }
    return stu;
}
```

And I call it in this matter:

```
ifstream ifile("test.bin", ios::binary);
Student stu2;
stu2 = Student::Deserialize(ifile);
```

### Edit

As requested, here is the serialize function:

```
void Student::Serialize(ostream &out)
{
    cout << "Serializing student: " << name << endl;
    if (out.good())
    {
        out.write(name, 20); // name
        out.write((char *) &num, sizeof(num)); // num
        out.flush();
    }
    if (out.bad())
    {
        cerr << "Read error on IO operation" << endl;
    }
    if (out.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Serialization failed" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Serialization succesful" << endl;
    }
}
```

And the content of the file `test.bin` in hex as given by `od`, followed by the contents of the deserialized object:

```
0000000 654a 6e61 4c2d 6375 4e00 0072 0000 0000
0000020 8150 d609 ffff ffff ffff ffff
0000034

Name: Hello
Number: 4294967295
```

Comment: You should also show the `Serialize()` function and how it is called. Do a hexdump of the `test.bin` file. What is the length of the file?

Comment: Don't you think that the `Serialize()` function would be kind of relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Serialize()` function is saving the members of `Student`.  Your `Deserialize()` function is trying to read an entire `Student` at once.  That won't work for a multitude of reasons, data alignment being only one of them (even if you took care of everything else just perfectly.)

So, have both methods work exactly the same way: either serialize and deserialize member by member, or serialize and deserialize the entire class.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! If you are willing, could you provide a resource where I could learn more about why the original code did not work?

Comment: both "c++ memory alignment" and "c++ data alignment" when googled appear to yield innumerable relevant articles, including wikipedia articles.